# Potatoes outgrowing bag - too high to hill/earth up

Tags: potatoes

I've grown some potatoes in foot high bags and have been steadily earthing them up as they grow. The stem has now reached about two feet so any earth I put on top simply falls off.

Is it best to repot them in a larger container or leave it to grow to avoid damaging them?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just drop them, original bag and all, into a taller bag and keep adding dirt?  I use burlap coffee bean sacks from a local importer.... about 3 ft tall.  1 ft tall definitely won't do the trick, or, at least, not to the degree you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Shoot, just add straw instead of soil.  In fact that is how a lot of potato growers deal with your same problem.  Potatoes grown in pots or in the garden soil, I use a tomato cage and just keep stuffing straw instead of soil always keeping a good 6" at first of green top growth above the straw and later I allow a foot of top growth.  Works very well.